# Constraint Exclusion With PreparedStatments - PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

According to PostgreSQL documentation section: [5.9.6. Caveats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

> Constraint exclusion only works when the query's `WHERE` clause contains
>   constants. A parametrized query will not be optimized, since the
>   planner cannot know which partitions the parameter value might select
>   at run time.

Is there any library that provide some sort of `PreparedStatement`(I mean only SQL injection facility since we could not benefit from optimized performance of `PreparedStatement`) and also generates a static SQL string so we could benefit from Constraint Exclusion feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to switch over to prepared statements after a certain number of invocations. See [Connection to the Database](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) the variable `prepareThreshold` and also follow the link in that section.

In your case you can either try the value `0` or a very large number. I'm not sure whether `0` means "use prepared statements immediately" or "never use prepared statements". A large number should prevent prepared statements for sure.

Using this method, your Java-code still uses `PreparedStatement` and the driver is responsible for proper quoting. The protocol between the driver and the server will use "unprepared" statements.

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons-lang has a basic escaping method ... javadoc:

For example,

```
statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MOVIES WHERE TITLE='" + 
   StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql("McHale's Navy") + 
   "'");
```

At present, this method only turns single-quotes into doubled single-quotes ("McHale's Navy" => "McHale''s Navy"). It does not handle the cases of percent (%) or underscore (_) for use in LIKE clauses.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String%29

HTH